# Formula for summation series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know if there exists any formula for this given expression.
Can anyone help?

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^T (i+k) $$

Comment: There is one. But, don't you think it would good to show what you already tried ?

Comment: I am not at all aware of multiplication series. Once I am through it I can find the general term and then apply the formulae of summation of series.

Comment: Try the  product first with a few numbers and identify the pattern.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am unable to observe any pattern. This is because the multiplication series involves i also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^T (i+k)=\sum_{i=1}^N (i+1)(i+2)\cdots(i+T)=\\
\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(i+T)!}{i!}=T!\cdot \sum_{i=1}^N {i+T\choose T}=\\
T!\cdot\left(\sum_{i=0}^N {i+T\choose T}-1\right)=T!\cdot\left({N+T+1\choose T+1}-1\right).$$

Comment: `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` might help with the formatting...

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^T (i+k) = \frac{1}{T+1} \{(i+T+1)-i\} \prod_{k=1}^T(i+k)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{T+1}\left\{ \prod_{k=1}^{T+1} (i+k) - \prod_{k=1}^{T+1} (i-1+k)\right \}$$

Therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^T (i+k) = \frac{1}{T+1} \sum_{i=1}^N \left\{ \prod_{k=1}^{T+1} (i+k) - \prod_{k=1}^{T+1} (i-1+k)\right \} $$

$$= \frac{1}{T+1} \left\{ \prod_{k=1}^{T+1} (N+k) - \prod_{k=1}^{T+1} k \right \}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{T+1} \left \{ \frac{(N+T+1)!}{N!} - (T+1)! \right \}$$
$$ = T! \left \{ {N+T+1 \choose N} - 1 \right \}$$

Comment: oops, I got sniped :(

Comment: `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` might help with the formatting...