# How to evaluate $ \sum_{x=1}^{N} \frac{(T+x)!}{x!} $?

Tags: summation, factorial

WolframAlpha provides the solution as $$  \sum_{x=1}^{N} \frac{(T+x)!}{x!}= \frac{(N+1)(N+T+1)!-(N+1)!(T+1)!}{(T+1)(N+1)!}$$ but I am unsure as to how this is obtained.

For some background, the summation on the left was obtained from a series like this... $$ (1 + 1) \cdot (1 + 2) \cdot (1 + 3) \cdot \ldots (1 + T) +\\ (2 + 1) \cdot (2 + 2) \cdot (2 + 3) \cdot \ldots (2 + T) +\\
 (3 + 1) \cdot (3 + 2) \cdot (3 + 3) \cdot \ldots (3 + T) +\\
 \ldots + \\
 (N + 1) \cdot (N + 2) \cdot (N + 3) \cdot \ldots (N + T) $$

If it is any help.

Comment: related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798964/formula-for-summation-series/2799027#2799027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity is equivalent to
$$\sum_{x=0}^{N} \binom{T+x}{T}=1+\frac{1}{T!}\sum_{x=1}^{N} \frac{(T+x)!}{x!}
\\=
1+\frac{(N+1)(N+T+1)!-(N+1)!(T+1)!}{(T+1)!(N+1)!}
=\binom{N+T+1}{T+1}.
$$
Now take a look at [Sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k+m}{m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341156/sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-binomkmm) where $n=N$, $m=T$.